# Array of strings to dataframe with word columns

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe

What's the easiest way to get from an array of strings like this:

```
arr = ['abc def ghi', 'def jkl xyz', 'abc xyz', 'jkl xyz']
```

to a dataframe where each column is a single word and each row contains 0 or 1 depending if the word appeared in the string. Something like this:

```
   abc def ghi jkl xyz
0    1   1   1   0   0
1    0   1   0   1   1
2    1   0   0   0   1
3    0   0   0   1   1
```

EDIT: Here is my approach, which to me seemed like a lot of python looping and not using the built in pandas functions

```
labels = (' ').join(arr)
labels = labels.split()
labels = list(set(labels))
labels = sorted(labels)

df = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros((len(arr), len(labels))), columns=labels)
cols = list(df.columns.values)

for i in range(len(arr)):
    for col in cols:
        if col in arr[i]:
            df.set_value(i, col, 1)
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but this site is not meant to solve your tasks, but to help you with problems you occur on your way to solve them.
So, what does your code look like so far?

Comment: i included my own code in the question, which works but seemed like a lot of manual python loops. i thought there might be an easier way to do it with pandas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDITED - reduced to 3 essential lines:

```
import pandas as pd

arr = ['abc def ghi', 'def jkl xyz', 'abc xyz', 'jkl xyz']

words = set( ' '.join( arr ).split() )
rows  = [ { w : int( w in e ) for w in words } for e in arr ]
df    = pd.DataFrame( rows )

print( df )
```

Result:

```
   abc  def  ghi  jkl  xyz
0    1    1    1    0    0
1    0    1    0    1    1
2    1    0    0    0    1
3    0    0    0    1    1
```

Comment: thanks and sorry for now including my code from the beginning. yours runs a little faster than mine

Comment: Sure. You can reduce it to 2 lines by creating the DataFrame directly on the result of the rows list comprehension, but this is a bit more readable :)

Comment: @pietz if this solution helped, please accept it (tick mark to side) to confirm resolution.